# Unable to compile mod_mam_sql in ejabberd-18.01

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

ERROR - function sql_insert__mark_/2 undefined. (LINE NO - 242,217)
      - unknown type specifier 'H' (LINE NO - 150)

I am trying to compile this module separately but cannot because of this issue.I have included all the necessary hrl files. mod_mam and mod_mam_mnesia compiles perfectly but this one fails.

Ejabberd version - 18.01

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compile that module because you applied some changes in it, it may be easier to simply download all ejabberd source code, compile all of it, then make your changes, and compile again.